# error: <identifier> expected nm="Sam";

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public abstract class Player {
    abstract String nm;
    public abstract void displayDetails();
}

class Booking extends Player {
nm = "Sam";           

    void displayDetails() {
        System.out.println("Name is:" + nm);
    }
}
```

// code is producing error: identifier expected nm="sam";

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Is `abstract String` valid in `java` ?

Comment: I apologize for that mistake of mine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, you should keep the expression inside block only. You can't keep `nm = "Sam";` there, move it inside the instance initialization block

```
import java.util.*;

public abstract class Player {
    String nm; // instance fields cant be declared as abstract
    public abstract void displayDetails();
}

class Booking extends Player {
    { // instance initialization block
      nm = "Sam";
    }

    void displayDetails() {
        System.out.println("Name is:" + name);
    }
}
```

Comment: While I appreciate the technical correctness of this answer, the entire world would be better off if you put that code in a constructor and not an instance initialization block.

Comment: @ChrisHayes : It can be even inside the instance initialization block. Any reason you have?

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran It *works* inside there, but that is not at all a habit that a new programmer should be picking up. Use of constructors should be encouraged. Instance initializer blocks should only be used when their nuances are fully understood.